# Extract data table from oracle data base 12c to csv file to the client machine?

Tags: oracle, csv, plsql, client

I need to extract data table from oracle database 12c to csv file to the client machine using PLSQL,
not **database directory and not using spool**,
I have searched too much and don't found any solution.
So, if you can help me it'll be appreciated.

Comment: PL/SQL have no access to your machine, it is executed at the database sode

Comment: Why do you have to use PL/SQL and why can't you use spool? What can you do - can you run a query in a client application (e.g. SQL Developer) on the client machine, copy the CSV result, and paste that into a local document? (If so, not sure why spooling would be an issue...)

Comment: With SQLcl you may also create a "correct" CSV without any code by using `/*CSV*/` instruction

Comment: Or `set sqlformat csv` - both work in SQLcl or SQL Developer.

Comment: *"I want to do this task and I can't use the only two tools which would allow me to accomplish this task."*  Ho hum. The problem is, PL/SQL runs in the database which runs on the database server and has no built-in means of communicating with the client.  So what tools are you allowed to use? Oracle Apex? Python? Shell scripts? REST API? ODBC calls from Excel?